# Need to write interrupt based java module

Tags: java

I want to write a interrupt based java module. which will raise a read interrupt when ever any data received from UDP socket. So that i need not to poll every time to check if data is preasent.

Please help.

Regards,
Aj

Comment: ajayk - You need to invest some time in solving the problem before SO users can help you. We won't write your programs for you. If you're unsure where to start, try looking for introductory material on using Threads in java, and on socket programming with UDP.

Comment: In fact, if this is a simple program (like a homework problem), you probably won't be interested in Threads, just socket programming

Comment: Add homework tag if it as a Homework, and always learn to show us your progress first

Comment: I don't want the full program. I know how the thread and socket works.
I want just an idea how to start.I have already wrote the code which is working on polling method. In this method i have to keep checking if something has received on not.I want to know if it is possible to write a code which will notify me as soon as some data is ready to process.
Hope you understand my problem

Answer (score 1):

Sun has a detailed tutorial on using UDP in Java:

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/networking/datagrams/index.html